# Mixing stacked and unstacked bars in single graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to mix stacked and unstacked bars in one graph.

Here is sample code:

```
Indicators <- c("Z","X","C","NO C","NA C","LOW C","HIGH C","D","E","F","G","H","LOW H","MED H","HIGH H",
                "I","LOW I","MED I","HIGH I","J","LOW J","MED J","HIGH J")

Class_1 <- c(0.44,0.01,"",0.6,0.13,0.11,0.16,0.08,0.01,0.14,0.21,"",0.55,
0.23,0.22,"",0.4,0.31,0.29,"",0.41,0.23,0.36)

data <- data.frame(Indicators,Class_1)
```

How can I make a graph with both unstacked and stacked bars? I really appreciate all the help there is! Thanks!

Comment: Both for your benefit and ours, if the question is about plotting, can you get the data into the shape you need it first, and post that? Like I'm assuming you want to separate "LOW H" into some sort of category column (low, high, no) and letter column. You're also mixing data types with the way you've set up your data, at least as far as making the sample to post: putting `""` in a numeric vector turns it into a character vector

Answer (score 2):

Basically you want a stacked barchart even if for some categories there is nothing to stack. To this end you have to do some data wrangling and cleaning like getting rid of the empty value rows and splitting the `Indicators` column in two:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

data1 <- data |> 
  filter(Class_1 != "") |> 
  mutate(Class_1 = as.numeric(Class_1)) |> 
  separate(Indicators, into = c("level", "which"), fill = "left") |> 
  replace_na(list(level = "Total"))

ggplot(data1, aes(which, Class_1, fill = level)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @stefan, Thanks for the answer. I was wondering how to use the separate function when variable names are longer. I've edited the question and code. Also, is it possible to have the full names for the level? (right side of the graph). Could you please help me with that? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Update II:

```
library(tidyverse)

my_pattern1 <- c("No|Non|Low-risk|High-risk|Low|Medium|High")

data %>% 
  filter(Class_1 != "") %>% 
  mutate(x = case_when(str_detect(Indicators, 'CSA|childhood sexual abuse') ~ "Childhood sexual abuse",
                       str_detect(Indicators, 'discrimination') ~ "discrimination"),
         y = str_extract(Indicators, my_pattern1)) %>% 
  mutate(z = str_remove_all(Indicators, my_pattern1)) %>% 
  mutate(y= ifelse(is.na(y), "Total", y)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = z, y = as.numeric(Class_1), fill= y))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

[image]

Update: (@camille is right. I now adapted my answer and removed the first one)

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
  separate(Indicators, c("Indicators_1",  "Indicators_2")) %>% 
  mutate(Indicators_3 = ifelse(is.na(Indicators_2), "Total", Indicators_1),
         Indicators_2 = coalesce(Indicators_2, Indicators_1)) %>% 
  filter(Class_1 != "") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Indicators_2, y = as.numeric(Class_1), fill= Indicators_3))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack")
```

[image]

Comment: A scale with this many colors is nearly impossible to read. If there are distinct categories in the data (low, high, med, ...) why not use them?

Comment: Good point. I adapted please see my update.

Comment: Hi @TarJae,  Thanks for the answer. I was wondering how to use the separate function when variable names are longer. I've edited the question and code.  Also, is it possible to have the full names for the level? (right side of the graph). Could you please help me with that? Thanks!!!

Comment: What do you mean with fullname High C High H High J low C low H etc... ?

Comment: Yes. And I've updated the variable names. I couldn't quite get how to properly use separate function on longer names.

Comment: I got a -1 for the detailed legend. Anyway I will update my final solution.

Comment: Hi @TarJae, thanks for the update, I think that the purple bars should be stacked into the first bar (Childhood sexual abuse) and that there should be a "No" and "Non-contact" indicator. Also, if it's possible, can the x axis names be ordered in the original order that is non-alphabetically ordered?